# "Forests slow down army movement" translation to Latin

Tags: translation-check, sentence-translation

*Forests slow down army movement*

> Silve motum exercitus retardant.

`Silva` - 1st declension, plural nominative is `Silve`

`motus` - 4th declension, in accusative `motum`

`exercitus` - 4th declension, in genitive `exercitus` - movement **of** an army

`retardo, retardare` - 1st conjugation, indicative, plural, 3rd person - `retardant`

---

*Army movement is slowed down by forests*

> Motus exerciti a silvis retardatur.

`silvis` - plural ablative of `silva`

`retardatur` - passive indicative, 1st conjugation, 3rd person singular

---

Are these translations correct?

In the second one is `a` the correct word to say `by what` the movement is slowed?

Am I correct in using ablative of `silva` here, or should it be stated differently?

I know word order is not the most fixed thing here but probably some kind of order is preferred for this two sentences? Is my word order okay, then?

Comment: It should be _silvae_ and _exercituum_ (in plural,) if I am not mistaken

Comment: In your first example *exercitus* is the correct  4thConj. genitive singular, If you decide the second example should be singular keep that same gen sing. *Silve* is the medieval nom pl of *silva.* As Rafael says, it would be *silvae* in classical Latin, He's right about *exercituum* too, for 4th gen. pl.

Comment: @Rafael @Hugh Thank you for comments. Should translation for `army` be `exercitus` in plural or in singular however?:-)

Comment: @PrzemysławP I think _army_ as uncountable is an English-specific idiom. Just from intuition, it makes more sense to me to use the plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Forests slow down army movement.
>   *<del>Silve</del> Silvae motum exercitus retardant.*

The only error here is misspelling the first word.
The plural nominative (and singular genitive and dative) of *silva* is *silvae*.

Another question is whether *exercitus* should be singular or plural.
If forests slow down the movement of an army or the army (one at a time), I would go with singular.
However, if it refers to movement of armies in general, then I would use plural.

However, the English original is not "the movement of an army", "the movement of the army", or "the movement of armies", but "army movement".
In this context "army" behaves much like an adjective, and it might be a good idea to translate it as one.
You could use *motus militaris* (accusative as needed here: *motum militarem*) for "army movement".
It all depends on how you exactly read the English expression "army movement".

> Army movement is slowed down by forests.
>   *Motus <del>exerciti</del> exercitus  <del>a</del>  silvis retardatur.*

This is a passive version of the first sentence.
The subject becomes an agent and the object becomes a subject.
This is mostly executed correctly, but there are minor problems.

First, *exercitus* is fourth declension so the genitive is *exercitus*.
In fact, the genitive stays the same in your two sentences, whether you choose singular or plural.
If you choose an adjective instead, it has to be in the same form as *motus* (masculine singular nominative).

Second, the agent does not always take the preposition *a(b)*.
The rule of thumb is that a human agent (some say "animate" instead of "human") takes the preposition, but others don't.
For more details, I refer you to [this question about deciding which agents are human or animate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/840/79).

The word order is perfectly fine in both translations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems however *silve* is acceptable, according to Hugh's comment under question and [this](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/latin/advanced/popup/grammar-table.htm): singular: *carta*, plural: *carte*

Comment: I can't give a technical argument, but it just doesn't sound right to me to use _exercitus_ as a singular noun unless the sentence is referred to a specific army.

Comment: @PrzemysławP The form *silve* might indeed be possible in later Latin, but certainly not in classical Latin. Unfortunately I'm quite ignorant of post-classical developments, so I can't comment much. I don't know if *silve* ever became the only option. But this is a minor detail, and depends on the Latin course you are taking or other material you are using.

Comment: @Rafael In Finnish I would certainly use the singular in this situation (when referring to armies in general), although the plural would be possible too. It's no proof that it should be the same way in Latin, of course. I don't know what's idiomatic in Latin.